# Querying data by week range and row value

Tags: google-sheets, formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google sheet data, arranged as per the screenshot below, where I am trying to query range A1 to C to return records occurred in the previous week `(weeknum(now)-1)` AND having specific status, i.e. `open` and `closed`. 
I have managed to write a similar query for a single column only, specifically for "B", which works fine:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({B2:B,if(len(B2:B),weeknum(B2:B),)}," select Col1 where Col2 = "&weeknum(now())&"",1))
```

[image]

What I need, however, is something like this

```
QUERY(A1:C, "Select B, C, D WHERE B = "&weeknum(now())-1&" "AND (C = 'Open' OR C = 'Closed'"),1)
```

i.e.

*ALL EVENTS FOR PREVIOUS WEEK; WITH STATUS OPEN OR CLOSED*

though I know query does not operate with `WEEKNUM()` and thus the above apparently does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try and see if it works:

(EDITED)

```
={B1:D1; ArrayFormula(query({B2:D,if(len(B2:B),weeknum(B2:B),)}, "Select Col1, Col2, Col3 where (Col2 = 'Open' OR Col2 = 'Closed') AND Col4 = "&weeknum(now())-1&"", 0))}
```

An alternative (and easier) way would be to use filter:

```
={B1:D1; filter(B:D, (C:C="Open")+(C:C="Closed"), weeknum(B:B)=weeknum(today())-1)}
```

Comment: One more question, can you clarify why we are having {B1:D1; in front of the filter function?

Comment: The {} creates an array with B1:D1 in the first row (so it basically copies the headers) and the filter underneath.